# Clue about how to start solving a Big-Theta problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been trying solve the following problem for some time and I just cannot find how to start. I will very much appreciate any feedback.

Does Big-Theta(n^3 + 2^n + 1) = Big-Theta(n^3) hold? I have to justify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is 
$$
\Theta(n^3 + 2^n + 1) = \Theta(n^3)?
$$

Since $2^n / n^3 \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, there do not exist nonnegative constants $C_1, C_2$ such that
$$
C_1 n^3 \leq (n^3 + 2^n + 1) \leq C_2 n^3
$$
for all naturals $n$. Therefore, the answer is no.

Edit after a comment by OP:

Is 
$$
\Theta(n^3 + 2 n + 1) = \Theta(n^3)?
$$

The question means:

If $f(n) = \Theta(n^3 + 2 n + 1)$ as $n \to \infty$, is then also $f(n) = \Theta(n^3)$ as $n \to \infty$, and vice versa?

In this case, the answer is yes, for suppose 
$
f(n) = \Theta(n^3 + 2 n + 1)
$ 
as 
$n \to \infty$; this means there are nonnegative constants $C_1, C_2$ such that
$$
C_1 f(n) \leq n^3 + 2 n + 1 \leq C_2 f(n)
$$
for all naturals $n$. Then 
$$
\frac{C_1}{4} f(n)
\leq
\frac14(2n + 1) + \frac14 n^3
\leq
n^3 \leq C_2 f(n)
,
$$
for all $n \geq 1$,
so $f(n) = \Theta(n^3)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Similarly for the converse.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake when writing the problem. It is:  Does Big-Theta(n^3 + 2*n + 1) = Big-Theta(n^3) hold? The difference is in 2*n instead of 2^n. However, did you notice that Big-Theta is in both sides of the equals sign? I guess that in this situation f(x) is not (n^3 + 2*n + 1) but f(x)=Big-Theta(n^3 + 2*n + 1). Am I correct?